# How to compare 2 row data value in single column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════╦═══════════════╗
║ EMPID ║   DATE    ║ TIME  ║ TYPE ║    STATUS     ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════╬═══════════════╣
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime        ║
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 14:00 ║ out  ║ Early Leaving ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime        ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 17:40 ║ out  ║ Ontime        ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 10:30 ║ in   ║ LateComing    ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 13:00 ║ out  ║ EarlyLeaving  ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════╩═══════════════╝
```

I'm having employee checkin and check out status now what i need is, i want to compare value of status column and display the result

**Example** using case statement in select:

```
when Min(status)='Ontime' and max(status)='Ontime' then 'Present'

when Min(status)='Ontime' and max(status)='Early Leaving' then 'Left Early'
```

I need final **output** as:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ EMPID ║   DATE    ║ TIME  ║ TYPE ║    STATUS     ║ DAYSTATUS  ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime        ║            ║
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 14:00 ║ out  ║ Early Leaving ║ Left Early ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime        ║            ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 17:40 ║ out  ║ Ontime        ║ present    ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 10:30 ║ in   ║ LateComing    ║            ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 13:00 ║ out  ║ EarlyLeaving  ║ Absent     ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.*,
        CASE WHEN a.type = 'IN' THEN ''
            ELSE
            CASE WHEN b.IN = 'Ontime' AND b.Out = 'Ontime' THEN 'Present'
                WHEN b.IN = 'Ontime' AND b.Out = 'Early Leaving' THEN 'Left Early'
                ELSE 'Absent'
            END
        END DAYSTATUS
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  EmpID,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'IN' THEN status END) `IN`,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'OUT' THEN status END) `OUT`
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY EmpID
        ) b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8d0/5)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ EMPID ║   DATE    ║ TIME  ║ TYPE ║    STATUS     ║ DAYSTATUS  ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime        ║            ║
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 14:00 ║ out  ║ Early Leaving ║ Left Early ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime        ║            ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 17:40 ║ out  ║ Ontime        ║ Present    ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 10:30 ║ in   ║ LateComing    ║            ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 13:00 ║ out  ║ EarlyLeaving  ║ Absent     ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for u reply but we have one issue we are having 4 branch in which 2 branches has in and out type(device) but for other two branches we have only in device and we have to count log out time by using maximum in time

Answer (score 1):

Try it using case and variables

```
     select @empId:=EmpId as EmpId,@date:=date as Date, time, type,@status:=status as status,
   case type 
     when 'out'
        then
         case(select status from mytable where empid = @empId AND date = @date AND type = 'in')
         when 'Ontime' then
            case(@status)
              when 'EarlyLeaving' then 'EarlyLeaving'
              when 'ontime'       then 'Present'
             end
          when 'LateComing' then
             case(@status)
              when 'EarlyLeaving' then 'Absent'
             end
         end 
     when 'in' then ''
  end as daystatus    
from mytable
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1a5e/88)

**OUTPUT**

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ EMPID ║   DATE    ║ TIME  ║ TYPE ║    STATUS    ║  DAYSTATUS   ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime       ║              ║
║     5 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 14:00 ║ out  ║ EarlyLeaving ║ EarlyLeaving ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 09:30 ║ in   ║ Ontime       ║              ║
║     6 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 17:40 ║ out  ║ Ontime       ║ Present      ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 10:30 ║ in   ║ LateComing   ║              ║
║     7 ║ 2012-03-1 ║ 13:00 ║ out  ║ EarlyLeaving ║ Absent       ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: it works if we have both out and in parameters but if i have only in and i want to check using maximum in time then

Comment: @vishu Sorry I didnt got your point .. have u seen the fiddle ?

Comment: @vishu but you are representing status only at out time .. and I suppose it should be like that .. Anyways please explain mw what do you want me to change ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for u reply but we have one issue we are having 4 branch in which 2 branches has in and out type(device) but for other two branches we have only in device and we have to count log out time by using maximum in time

Comment: im comparing value of status column like if ontime for in as as well as ontime for out then it would be present

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic

```
when TYPE = 'out' and STATUS ='Early Leaving' then 'Left Early'

when TYPE = 'out' and STATUS ='Ontime' then 'present'

Else 'Absent'
```